# Check n numbers if they are perfect squares and how to calculate their sum?

Tags: c, sum, perfect-square

the problem I have to solve is checking n numbers introduced by the user if they are perfect squares and then I have to calculate the sum of these perfect squares. I understand how to do these, but my code simply doesn't work at the part which should calculate the sum. I don't know what to do.

```
int main()
{
int n, num, sum, iVar;
float fVar;

    sum=0;
    fVar=sqrt((double)num);
    iVar=fVar;

printf("Introduce numbers, press 0 to stop:");

    for(n=0; ; n++)
        {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if(num==0){break;}
        if(iVar==fVar)
            {
                sum+=num;
            }
        }

printf("Sum of all perfect squares is: %d", sum);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: I suggest that you consult with one of the class TAs (teacher's assistant), or hire a tutor. The code you've posted indicates that you need more help than SO can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below. For running infinite loop you can use `while(num)` instead of `for(n=0; ; n++)`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
  int sum = 0;
  double num = 0;

   printf("Introduce numbers, press 0 to stop:");

    scanf("%lf", &num);
    while(num)
        {
          int res =  sqrt(num);
          if((res*res)==num)
           {
                sum+=num;
           }

          scanf("%lf", &num);
       }

   printf("Sum of all perfect squares is: %d", sum);
   return 0;  
}
```